# ANTLR4 - named function arguments

Tags: antlr4

My goal is to generate parser that could handle following code with named function parameters and nested function calls

```
fnCallY(namedArgStr = "xxx", namedArgZ=fnCallZ(namedArg="www"))
```

G4 lang file:

```
val : type_string
     | function_call
     ;

function_call : function_name=ID arguments='('argument? (',' argument)* ')';

argument : name=ID '=' value=val   ;

ID : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;

type_string : LITERAL;

fragment ESCAPED_QUOTE : '\\"';

LITERAL : '"' ( ESCAPED_QUOTE | ~('\n'|'\r') )*? '"'
        | '\'' ( ESCAPED_QUOTE | ~('\n'|'\r') )*? '\'';
```

```
@Override
public void exitFunction_call(Test.Function_callContext ctx) {
    List<Test.ArgumentContext> argument = ctx.argument();
    for (Test.ArgumentContext arg : argument) {
         Token name = arg.name;
         Test.ValContext value = arg.value;
         if (value.type_literal() == null || value.function_call() == null) {
             throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse argument value");
         }
     }
}
```

arg.name holds correct data, but i cannot make the parser to parse the part after `=`.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. But, the information you give contains programming errors. *The parser for your grammar parses the input just fine*. But, you forgot to mention the rule `WS : [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip;` because the input contains spaces. You should also add an EOF-terminated start rule: `start : function_call EOF;`. The listener method `exitFunction_call` that you give, in fact, doesn't compile. `type_literal()` does not existent in ValContext because the rule for `val` is `val : type_string | function_call ;`. For that rule, only `type_string()` and `function_call()` exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser is recognizing the `argument` `value`s.

(It's really valuable to learn the `grun` command line utility as it can test the grammar and tree structure without involving any of your own code)

[image]

This condition would appear to be your problem:

```
 if (value.type_literal() == null || value.function_call() == null)
```

One or the other will always be null, so this will fail.

```
 if (value.type_literal() == null && value.function_call() == null)
```

is probably what you want.